# How can I get task (container) health from the Docker REST api?

Tags: rest, docker

When running `docker ps` I get a nice list of all containers running on the particular host. Among other things, I can see the health of a container as reported by my own `HEALTHCHECK`.

How can I get this piece of information via the REST api? I'm putting together  a small agent which pulls data from the Docker REST api and submits it to a monitoring tool. I'd really like to monitor the health of containers.

If it's possible to pull this piece of information from the `/tasks` endpoint, then that would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

this should help

GET /containers/{id}/json

this should return json containing "Health" key
Health can contain below values:
"none" "starting" "healthy" "unhealthy"

Status is one of none, starting, healthy or unhealthy

```
"none" Indicates there is no healthcheck
"starting" Starting indicates that the container is not yet ready
"healthy" Healthy indicates that the container is running correctly
"unhealthy" Unhealthy indicates that the container has a problem
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/ContainerCreate